# Why does my function fail to create lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create 5 lists out of 1 data file, the error I keep getting states that "airlines is not defined", yet it is the first thing I define in the function, how is this possible? What should I do to correctly create a list of airlines, arrival times, departure times, prices, and flight number?

```
USAir,1269,6:15,10:57,210
Delta,5138,16:20,22:10,212
UNITED,6001,14:12,20:50,217
Delta,5054,12:30,20:22,227
UNITED,5949,9:30,14:43,264
JetBlue,1075,17:00,20:06,280
Delta,1263,6:00,11:30,282
Delta,3824,9:00,14:45,282
USAir,1865,16:55,21:33,300
USAir,3289,18:55,23:41,300
USAir,1053,8:00,13:02,300
USAir,2689,12:55,18:09,300
USAir,3973,9:25,14:00,302
USAir,3267,11:30,16:13,302
USAir,3609,13:25,18:28,302
USAir,3863,15:35,20:54,302
USAir,3826,17:45,23:19,302
USAir,1927,7:00,12:53,302
Delta,3601,12:00,17:29,307
Delta,4268,7:15,12:46,307
UNITED,4676,6:00,10:45,321
UNITED,4103,11:00,16:16,321
USAir,3139,11:51,16:29,332
JetBlue,475,7:30,10:42,340
USAir,3267,11:30,18:15,367
UNITED,2869,16:55,21:33,406
UNITED,2865,6:15,10:57,406
UNITED,2729,8:00,13:02,406
UNITED,2645,7:00,12:53,445
```

and the code I am using is

```
def getFlights():

    airlines = []
    flightNums = []
    depTimes = []
    arriveTimes = []
    prices = []

    fname = input("Enter name of data file: ")
    infile = open(fname, 'r')

    line = infile.readline()
    line = line.strip()


    while line != "":
        line = line.strip()
        airline, flightNum, depTime, arriveTime, price = line.split(',')
        airlines.append(airline)
        flightNums.append(flightNum)
        depTimes.append(depTime)
        arriveTimes.append(arriveTime)
        prices.append(price)
        line = infile.readline()
        line = line.strip()

    infile.close()
    return airlines, flightNums, depTimes, arriveTimes, prices

getFlights()
print(airlines, flightNums, depTimes, arriveTimes, prices)
```

Comment: Which line does it say you have an error on? Python should include the line where the error is in the error message.

Comment: You never put the return values from `getFlights()` into variables.

Comment: You shouldn't use `readline` directly. Instead just use the built-in iterator for files: `for line in infile:`

Comment: Also your code formatting is broken and in Python that changes the meaning of your program. It would be best if you fixed that in your question to ensure that your actual code is correctly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables inside a function are not accessible outside of the function call. If you want to use the returned values of `getFlights` you must assign them to variables in the calling context.

```
(airlines, flightNums, depTimes, arriveTimes, prices) = getFlights()
print(airlines, flightNums, depTimes, arriveTimes, prices)
```

Comment: Or even `print(*getFlights())` might be all that's required

Comment: Very true. I was assuming that the OP wanted to do more than just `print` the variables after parsing the file.

Answer (score 0):

What b4hand has said is correct, however, the Pythonic way of doing this is using `csv.reader` and a `with` statement, eg:

```
import csv

filename = input('Enter filename: ')
with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    airlines, flightNums, depTimes, arriveTimes, prices = zip(*csvin)
```